# Java Date conversion in String format (mm name_of_the_month yyyy)

Tags: java, date

I have a date in this format dd/MM/yyyy and I want to convert in string format like this "mm name of the month yyyy".

For example I have 25/02/2019 and I want an output like this "25 February 2019" in java 7.

How can I do?

Comment: String --parse--> Date --format--> String

Comment: With java 8 you can use `yourDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMMM yyyy"))`

Comment: When using Java 7 consider using [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of java.time, the modern Java date and time API, to Java 6 and 7. It’s the future-proof and programmer-friendly solution. Look into classes `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`.'

Comment: I found this solution: SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy"); that works for me